# How Can I Index a CSV File to Search Efficiently?

Tags: python, csv, search, dictionary, search-engine

I have a CSV file with over 400k rows and about 20 columns so it takes too much time for me to search the CSV when I'm looking for a certain value. I was wondering how I could map the file so that I can search it efficiently and quickly for a certain value.

Thank you in advance! I'm happy to answer any questions!

Comment: Have you tried memory mapping or using a SQL database?

Comment: No! I'm not at all familiar with DB options.

Comment: how are you going to search? do you know in which column to search or do you want to search for text in all columns (like in text file)?

Comment: You could try to use a [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) database by storing the rows/columns within tables and just use the `sqlite3` Python module to search through your data, or just use the `Pandas` module (which is probably easiest?)

Comment: @MaxU I know which column to search but not which row.

Comment: then try pandas.read_csv() as Mark proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can store the whole thing in RAM (i.e load it) I would use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_loc = 'C:/yourcsv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_loc, sep=',', header=0) #http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
df['name'] # would select a column called name
# This would show observations which start with STARBUC
match = df['name'].str.contains('(^STARBUC)')
print(df['name'][match].value_counts())
```

Etc. [This is a great tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) [and this](https://plot.ly/python/big-data-analytics-with-pandas-and-sqlite/)

Comment: So how would I search for a string in the whole csv?

Answer (score 3):

The [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function makes it fairly easy. Python does have [csv reading/writing functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) too.

Update: Here is [a link to a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403590/4938264) from the `pandas` creator on fast searching in `pandas`.

Comment: I've tried using the built-in CSV read module but like I hinted in the question it takes way too long!

Comment: ++ for the link to pd.searchsorted() - i didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

If I was doing something like this, I would load the cvs file into an [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) database file and then use the python bindings for SQLite to search the data. SQLite is free and widely used, so you can easily find support, code snippets, etc. This approach does require some basic database concepts, mostly simple SQL statements.

Comment: How would I load the CSV file into a SQLite file?

Comment: A tutorial on SQLite is out of scope for an SO question... But such tutorials are easy to find. Install SQLite and try it out, you'll have your solution going in a couple hours.